# FB.ui callback (FB is not defined)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I've been trying to crack this for quite some time now and I'm beginning to pull my hair out. I'm trying to get a callback from the share button, which I know to be possible.

When importing the script into my site I am receiving the error "FB is not defined"

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. What am I doing wrong? - It's been a long day.

Edit: It's sharing to Facebook perfectly fine, however the callback isn't doing anything.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    })
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

$(document).ready(function(){
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://xxxxxxxx.com',
  caption: '',
}, function(response) {
  if (response && response.post_id) {
    alert('Post was published.');
  } else {
    alert('Post was not published.');
  }}

);
});
</script>
```

My html:

```
<div class="fb-like" onclick="response()" data-href="https://xxxxxxxx.com" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you calling the Feed dialog using `FB.ui` anyway – didn’t you want to let the button handle that?

Comment: As for what you are doing wrong – you are calling `FB.ui` in `$(document).ready` – but because of the JS SDK being loaded asynchronously, it is not done initializing at this point, and therefor the `FB` object doesn’t exist yet. You should not call `FB.ui` automatically on page load anyway, that’s just bad UX – but as I already said, if you want the user to post when they click the `fb-like` button, then you don’t need to call the Feed dialog at all.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should follow the documentation to use fb sdk with jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: '{your-app-id}',
      version: 'v2.3' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.0
    });     
    $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback);
  });
});
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/v2.4